# How can you actually decrease the cursor speed?

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad

My mouse has a high DPI, which makes using any of the Acceleration and Sensitivity options in "Mouse and Touchpad" uncomfortable. I can set both to the lowest possible values, and it's still too fast. Oddly enough, there isn't even a mouse speed option listed, just acceleration. These are not the same thing, but these are the closest options I could find in the GUI.

In windows it's easy to set pointer speed scaling. I can't find any way to do this in Ubuntu. I would like to a) Have no acceleration at all, and b) Have the speed of the cursor be exactly 1/2 of the current speed.

For reference, I have tried two things which didn't work:

From [This page](http://ashonit.blogspot.ca/2013/03/configure-mouse-speed-in-xubuntu.html)

`xinput --set-prop 9 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4`

where 9 is the ID of my mouse, and varying the number 4 at the end should change constant decel. However, no matter what value I put there is changes nothing.

[Another answer](https://superuser.com/a/12657/631988) recommends editing your xorg.conf file to change MinSpeed and MaxSpeed, but this doesn't exist in recent Ubuntu versions.

So is there any other way to change this I am missing? Even if it's a bizarre hack, I just want to decrease the pointer speed to a sane level.

I am using Xubuntu based on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at everything you tried, especially the `xinput` command it should have worked.  I use Xubuntu, but I am logged in under the Xfce4 desktop and the speeds for my mouse changed using that command.  Maybe someone might see something here that I'm missing.  When you ran the `xinput` did you use the `list-props 9` to see what it supports?

Comment: Maybe even try that `xinput` command and putting the last number at 50 or 100 or something greater.  I put mine up to 1000 and the mouse looked like it would barely move at all.

Comment: Yeah, my assumption was initially that I had the wrong ID.

Comment: Did any higher numbers change the speed at all?

Comment: But, I've tried every ID or name in xinput list. Whether I use the ID or the name of an input the command doesn't appear to have an effect. Setting the last value to any value doesn't change anything, even if it's over 1000.

Comment: Maybe that type of mouse won't accept settings like that.

Comment: I assume it's not mouse specific, xinput should just be translating whatever raw input it gets. But I am not sure. Also I have this same issue with a logitech mx518 and a g700s, both of which are relatively common and old mice.

Comment: Interesting.  I run Xfce4 (Xubuntu 16.04) and it definitely changes the tracking speeds of mine.  It is the only way I know of on how to do it.